# Structs cannot be nil, but this is compiling

Tags: go

I'm playing with Go Playground and find this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
        e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
    return &MyError{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

So here I can see that `*MyError` implements `error` interface. However if I remove `&` in `error` func and return `MyError` instead, I receive compile time error: 
`prog.go:19: cannot use MyError literal (type MyError) as type error in return argument: MyError does not implement error (Error method has pointer receiver)`. OK I can understand that, so I can make the function `Error` like this and this will compile and run successfully:

```
func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
        e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
    return MyError{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}
```

Then I see in `main` func that there is check if `err` is `nil` so if I understand correctly it is perfectly possible func `error` to return `nil` in some situations. So it is possible for `MyError` struct to take `nil` values. But then if I try to compile this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
        e.When, e.What)
}

func run() error {
    return nil
    return MyError{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    var err2 MyError = nil

    fmt.Println(err2)
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

go compiler said that: `prog.go:27: cannot use nil as type MyError in assignment
 [process exited with non-zero status]`

Why in the upper case the compilation is successful and in this case the compilation fails?
Is it possible for structs to be `nil` (I guess not, but then why `run` func compiles?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first example, `*MyError` implemented the `error` interface. As you can see, it's a pointer, and a pointer can have the `nil` value.

```
var err *MyError
err == nil // true

var err *MyError = new(MyError)
err == nil // false
```

But in the second example, it is `MyError` which implements the `error` interface, and that is not a pointer any more.

```
var err MyError
err == MyError{} // true
&err == nil // false
err == nil // Compilation error
```

It is the adress of `err` this time that can be `nil`, not the variable itself.

---

As a comparison, consider the `int` type: `var i int`. You can check `i == 0` for instance, but it would be an error to test if `i == nil`, because `nil` is not an integer (exactly as it was not a `MyError` before). But you could still check if the address of `i` is `nil`: `&i == nil`.

---

EDIT

Be aware that this function will *always* return `nil` (the execution stops right after the first `return`):

```
func run() error {
    return nil
    return MyError{
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}
```

It compiles because the prototype of the function tells that it must return an `error`, and indeed, `nil` is a valid `error`, and so is a `MyError{}` variable. But try to change this function prototype to this one:

```
func run() MyError
```

You will see that the compilation fails, because `nil` is not a `MyError` variable, even though it is a valid value for the `error` type.

Comment: I understand this, but look at the `run` func. It returns MyError but also can return nil.

Comment: Aha, it makes sense now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

A nil interface is not the same as an interface containing a nil value.

In your question, you have seen that an interface (in your case, the builtin error interface) can be nil, and drawn an incorrect conclusion that every type that can implement the interface can also be nil.